# Yocto minimal eSDK - world-pkgdata

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I've been trying to generate minimal extensible sdk using Yocto 2.5 Sumo. I've cloned only the poky and meta-openembedded repositories. In local.conf I've set the SDK type to minimal and set [SDK_INCLUDE_PKGDATA](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-SDK_INCLUDE_PKGDATA). During the last task (do_populate_sdk_ext) bitbake throws that *locked-sigs-pkgdata.inc* is not found in this directory

> tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/world-pkgdata/

Find shows that this file is avaible here

> ./tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/meta-world-pkgdata/1.0-r0/image/world-pkgdata/locked-sigs-pkgdata.inc
>
> ./tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/meta-world-pkgdata/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/world-pkgdata/locked-sigs-pkgdata.inc

When I copy this file from on of above directories eSDK is correctly generated. I believe that this should be done automatically by one of recipe for poky/meta-openembedded. Probably I miss some config, but I'am unable to correctly identify the source of this problem.

Here is my bblayers.conf:

```
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
/work/build/yocto/poky/meta \
/work/build/yocto/poky/meta-poky \
/work/build/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
/work/build/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
/work/build/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
/work/build/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
/work/build/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-perl \
/work/build/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome \
/work/build/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
/work/build/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-initramfs \
/work/build/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
/work/build/yocto/openembedded-core/meta \
"
```

And my local.conf:

```
MACHINE = "genericx86-64"
BUILD_ARCH ?= "x86_64"
SDKMACHINE ?= "x86_64"
SDK_UPDATE_URL ?= "http://my-url/sdk-updater"
SDK_EXT_TYPE = "minimal"
SDK_INCLUDE_TOOLCHAIN = "0"
SDK_INCLUDE_PKGDATA = "1"
SSTATE_MIRRORS_append = " file://.* http://my-url/sstate/PATH \n"
DISTRO ?= "poky"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_ipk"
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = "commercial" 
CONF_VERSION = "1"
```

I've tested

> core-image-full-cmdline

and

> core-image-minimal-dev

on both I've the same problem.

Thanks for any help and clues how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could You kindly check clean build this recipe *meta-world-pkgdata* ($ bitbake -c cleanall meta-world-pkgdata) and rerun build image again ?

Comment: .inc files are used in recipes with "require" or "include" to reuse/share information or functionality between recipes. If such files are not there an error (when used require) or warning is raised during parsing the recipes. It is not clear to me why this error occurres during task execution.

Comment: @astor555 Hi, I've try this. Still the same issue. I've even try to create project from scratch. I've tested Yocto 2.4, 2.5, master branch. I've even try the Toaster GUI to create project from zero. eSDK is generated correctly if I set SDK_INCLUDE_PKGDATA to 0, in other case it fails on all my tests. I'm try to think the this could be o problem with my system. I've try to build this using Docker and directly on my system. I've tested bash and zsh. Always ends with this error. Maybe I will try to install some virtual machine with different OS and test that, because I'm out of any other ideas.